# mysql query for elapsed time per day

Tags: mysql, time, syntax, elapsed

I have such this table as below and I trying to calculate the elapsed time for which the value "relay" is to 1 per day by creating a view.

```
id, date, time, dateandtime,timestamp,sensor,temperature,humidity,status
xx   15/03/2018 11:39:00    15/03/2018 11:39:00.0   15/03/2018 11:39    sensor1 23  41  0
xx   15/03/2018 11:40:00    15/03/2018 11:40:00.0   15/03/2018 11:39    sensor2 23  41  1
```

Here is the query that I come with, however the output is not as except for the past or previous day...

select date,time,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,MAX(Date), timestamp) as minutes FROM temperaturedata where relay = 1 group by date

Here is the results:

```
date time minutes
2018-03-15 11:39:00 699 
2018-03-16 11:01:00 661
```

Some clarifications, I am trying to get how long per day and hour the status has been set to 1.

something like:

```
date, starttime, endtime, minutes;
```

As starttime would be when the first of instance to 1 appears and endtime the last time, minutes the total amount of minutes for which the status was to 1.

hope it make a bit more sense. :)

Any guidance would be more than welcome.

THanks.
J.

Comment: What outcome do you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the initial post.

Comment: Since you 'group by date' applying the `MAX()` function to 'date' makes no sense. You probably want to apply it to 'timestamp'. You don't seem to use 'dateandtime'? But this is how far I can go, because I don't understand what you want to achieve. Your question is incomplete.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is not really understand able :( I am trying to view how long per day and maybe also per hour le status was to 1.